# job-launching-gateway dynamic job parameter

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I am using Spring batch integration, I have to pass the job parameter dynamically. Below is my service activator class which converts my message into JobLaunchRequest.

Note : no channel name specified as it is inside the chain.

```
<int:service-activator id="msgToJob">
    <bean class="org.xyz.transformer.MessageToJob">
        <property name="job" ref="myJob"/>
    </bean>
</int:service-activator>
```

How can I pass the job reference dynamically either from the payload or from the header etc.,?
Please suggest suitable solution.

I have a plan to use router to determine the job and use the corresponding service activator channel. Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<int:header-enricher ... >
    <int:header name="jobRef" expression="@someJob" />
</int:header-enricher>
```

With runtime SpEL expressions in Spring Integeration, `@` references a bean in the application context.

Comment: Tried with the above example and it works like a charm! one more quick question: @someJob - can this be dynamic. In a short, someJob bean will be identified later by the dynamic input.

Comment: Please ignore the above comment, I have taken the jobId from the application context and pass it..Thanks for your quick reply.